# Ring $R'$ with $R\subset R'\subset T$ where $R$, $T$ integrally closed and obtained by a purely inseparable extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, separable-extension

Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain with field of fractions $K$. Let $M/K$ be a purely inseparable extension and let $T$ be $R$'s integral closure in $M$. Consider a subring $R\subset R'\subset T$ and put $L$ its field of fractions and $S$ the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. We have $R\subset R'\subset S\subset T$ and purely inseparable extensions $K\subset L\subset M$.

> **Question.** is $R'$ automatically integrally closed, i.e. is $R'=S$ ?

---

$
\newcommand{\P}{\mathfrak{P}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}
\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
$I don't remember exactly how the question came about but I know it came up when reading the proof of the theorem below from Gerald J. Janusz's **Algebraic Number Fields**. For more details see the final sentence of the post.

> **Theorem 6.1** Let $R$ be a Dedekind ring with field of fractions $K$ and let $L$ be a finite field extension of $K$. Then the integral closure of $R$ in $L$ is a Dedekind domain.

The proof is in two steps. Considering the intermediate field $K\subset E\subset L$ of all separable elements of $L$ over $K$ one reduces the question to two special cases: separable extension and purely inseparable extension. In the purely inseparable case the author proves something that can be generalized as follows:

> **Lemma.** Let $R$ be integrally closed with field of fractions $K$ of characteristic $p$ and consider a purely inseparable extension $L/K$. Let $S$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$ and consider a subring $R\subset R'\subset S$. Then the inclusion $i:R\to R'$ induces a bijection on spectra, i.e. $i^*:\Spec(R')\to\Spec(R),\P\mapsto\P\cap R$ is a bijection.

*Proof.* One first notices that
$$S=\{x\in L\mid \exists n\in\N,~x^{p^n}\in R\}$$
Indeed, if $x\in L$ satisfies $x^{p^n}\in R$ then $x$ is integral over $R$ so that $x\in S$ by definition of $S$. Conversely, if $x\in L$ then, $L/K$ being purely inseparable, $x^{p^n}\in K$ for some $n$. If furthermore $x\in S$, then $x$ is integral over $R$ and so is $x^{p^n}\in K$. Since $R$ is integrally closed we have $x^{p^n}\in R$, and so both inclusions are proven.

1. $\mathbf{i^*}$ **is one to one.** First of all, if $\P$ is nonzero prime ideal of $R'$ then so is $\p=i^*(\P)$. Indeed, if $x\in\P$ is nonzero then for some $n$ we have
   $$x^{p^n}\in R\setminus 0$$
   and thus $x^{p^n}$ is a nonzero element of $\p$. Furthermore, we can reconstruct $\P$ from $\p$. Indeed, one shows
   $$\P=\{x\in R'\mid \exists n\in \N,~x^{p^n}\in\p\}$$
   Indeed, if $x\in R'$ satisfies $x^{p^n}\in\p\subset\P$, then, $\P$ being prime, $x\in\P$. And conversely, if $x\in\P$ then for some $n$, $x^{p^n}\in R$ so that $x^{p^n}\in\P\cap R=\p$.
2. $\mathbf{i^*}$ **is onto.** Let $\p$ be a prime of $R$ and put
   $$\p'=\{x\in R'\mid\exists n\in\N,~x^{p^n}\in\p\}$$
   $\p'$ is a prime ideal of $R'$. Indeed, if $x,y\in\p'$ and $r\in R'$ then there exist exponents $a,b,c\geq 0$ with $x^{p^a},y^{p^a}\in\p$ and $r^{p^c}\in R$. Thus if $n=\max\{a,b,c\}$ we have $(x+ry)^{p^n}\in \p$ so that $\p'$ is an ideal of $R'$. And if $xy\in\p'$ with $x,y\in R'$ and $y\notin\p'$ then for some $n\in\N$, $x^{p^n}\cdot y^{p^n}=(xy)^{p^n}\in\p$. With $\p$ prime and $y\notin\p'$ we have $x^{p^n}\in\p$ i.e. $x\in\p'$, and so $\p'$ is prime. Now one easily sees
   $$\p=R\cap\p'=i^*(\p')$$
   Indeed, $\p\subset\p'$ thus $\p\subset R\cap\p'$, and if $x\in R\cap\p'$ then $x^{p^n}\in\p$ with $x\in R$ and with $\p$ being a prime ideal of $R$, $x\in\p$. Therefore $i^*$ is onto.$\quad\blacksquare$

I was surprised that there would be a bijection on spectra without further hypothesis. The author of the book doesn't state the result above, rather he proves and uses it only for the subring $R'=S$ and I wondered whether this generalization is indeed a generalization or whether all subrings $R'$ are automatically integrally closed (whence my question, I think.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $R'/R$ is integral and $Frac(R')/Frac(R)$ is purely inseparable then it is immediate that $\mathfrak{p}\to \mathfrak{p}\cap R$ is a bijection $Spec(R')\to Spec(R)$.
- $\Bbb{F}_p[x^p,x^{p+1}]$ is not integrally closed in its fraction field and it is between the PID $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ and $\Bbb{F}_p[x^p]$.
- The problem of non-separable extensions $L/K$ is that $O_L$ doesn't have to be a finitely generated $O_K$-module (can't use the trace map which is identically $0$) and the $n=\sum_i f_i e_i$ stuffs may fail.

Comment: Thank you for the simple counter example. When you say that the first point is immediate, do you mean by the proof I give above or is there a shorter or more insightful explanation ?

Comment: I'd say for $\mathfrak{q}$ a prime ideal of $R$ and $p^n = [Frac(R'):Frac(R)]$ then $\{ a\in R', a^{p^n}\in \mathfrak{q}\}$ is a prime ideal of $R'$, and they are all of this form because $\{ a^{p^n},a\in \mathfrak{p}\}\subset \mathfrak{p}\cap R\subset \mathfrak{p}$